# How should I handle special characters in URLs?

Tags: php, url

I need to generate slugs for pages (e.g. /my-page-slug), where the slug will be generated from an ever-growing list of concepts. These concepts can contain special characters, diacritics, punctuation, etc.

My goal is to come up with a slug generation strategy that will be robust and avoid future conflicts, while considering URL readability and SEO.

I have looked at [RFC 3986][1] and at sites like Wikipedia and Quora to see how they handle specific cases, including:

- Spaces: Wikipedia uses underscores, Quora hyphens
- Diacritics (e.g. Molière)
- Other special characters (e.g. parenthesis, colon, comma, etc)

So far, it looks like there is no clear standard or best practice.

Are there specific libraries that already handle this? Or do I have to implement my own custom solution?

Right now, I'm considering a custom solution that does the following:

- URL encodes per RFC 3986
- Replaces some encoded characters for some "commonly found conventions" (e.g. hyphens for spaces, strip out apostrophes, etc)
- Strips out extra spaces

This is a proof-of-concept: Is this approach directionally valid?

```
function generateSlug($topic) {

  // URL encode
  $topic = rawurlencode($topic); // encodes according to RFC 3986: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html

  // Transform specific characters
  $topic = preg_replace('/%E2%80%93/', '-', $topic);  // decode en dash as hyphen
  $topic = preg_replace('/%E2%80%94/', '--', $topic);  // decode em dash as double-hyphen
  $topic = preg_replace('/%E2%80%A6/', '%20', $topic);  // convert ellipsis to space
  $topic = preg_replace('/%26/', '%20', $topic);  // convert ampersand to space
  $topic = preg_replace('/%2F/', '%20', $topic);  // convert forward to space
  $topic = preg_replace('/%3F/', '', $topic); // strip out question marks
  $topic = preg_replace('/%28/', '(', $topic);  // decode opening parenthesis
  $topic = preg_replace('/%29/', ')', $topic);  // decode closing parenthesis
  $topic = preg_replace('/%21/', '!', $topic);  // decode exclamation mark
  $topic = preg_replace('/%27/', '', $topic);  // strip apostrophes
  $topic = preg_replace('/%22/', '', $topic);  // strip double quotation
  $topic = preg_replace('/%2A/', '*', $topic);  // decode asterisk
  $topic = preg_replace('/%2C/', '', $topic);  // strip comma
  $topic = preg_replace('/%3A/', '', $topic);  // strip colon
  $topic = preg_replace('/%3B/', '', $topic);  // strip semicolon

  $topic = trim($topic);  // remove leading and trailing spaces
  $topic = preg_replace('/(%20)+/', '-', $topic);  // convert one or more spaces into single space

  return $topic;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the job:

```
public static function formatUrlPermalink ($var)
{
    $permasearch = explode(',', "À,Á,Â,Ã,Å,à,á,â,ã,å,Ò,Ó,Ô,Õ,Ø,ò,ó,ô,õ,ø,È,É,Ê,Ë,è,é,ê,ë,Ç,ç,Ì,Í,Î,Ï,ì,í,î,ï,Ù,Ú,Û,ù,ú,û,ÿ,Ñ,ñ,ß,ä,Ä,ö,Ö,ü,Ü");
    $permareplace = explode(',', "A,A,A,A,A,a,a,a,a,a,O,O,O,O,O,o,o,o,o,o,E,E,E,E,e,e,e,e,C,c,I,I,I,I,i,i,i,i,U,U,U,u,u,u,y,N,n,ss,ae,Ae,oe,Oe,ue,Ue");
    foreach ($permasearch as $key => $value) {
        $var = mb_ereg_replace ($value, $permareplace[$key], $var);
    }

    $var = preg_replace ("#(\s*\/\s*|\s*\+\s*|\s+)#", '-', strtolower($var));

    $permalinksseparator = '-';
    $var = mb_ereg_replace ("[^a-z0-9_{$permalinksseparator}]", '', $var, "imsr");
    $var = preg_replace ('/'.$permalinksseparator.'+/', $permalinksseparator, $var); // remove replicated separator
    $var = trim ($var, $permalinksseparator);

    return $var;
}
```

You can see how to adapt the special characters to your need on the first two lines. The rest just strips out spaces and replaces them with a '-' (the value of $permalinksseparator)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tested this out, but it doesn't handle cases like the following: C++ gets converted to "c", which causes issues with "C" or "C#". Or names with special characters (e.g. "Paul Ricœur")

Comment: I updated my original question with a slightly different approach that resolves some of these issues. Is this directionally valid?

Comment: Not sure about your new approach. You're basically urlencoding a string and then un-urlencoding parts of it. I may be wrong, but I think this seems to defeat the purpose of generating a readable permalink. Your examples of C++ and C# may best be handled by a special case generating "CPlusPlus" and "CSharp".

Comment: The challenge is that like "C++" I have thousands of cases like this that I can't handle on an individual basis. My approach approximates how I see Wikipedia and Quora handling URLs, where there is an ever-growing list of user-generated pages that they can't manually control.